# Curious (to me) behavior with slices in numpy array

Tags: python, arrays, numpy

This little python code:

```
   >>> a=np.random.rand(3,4,5)
   >>> a[0][:][3]
   >>> a[0,:,3]
```

Produces the results:

```
array([[[ 0.19080354,  0.45701919,  0.17411363,  0.45117827,  0.10413359],
            [ 0.86430848,  0.81831987,  0.27604238,  0.25587538,  0.72733844],
            [ 0.42065355,  0.63994284,  0.64540483,  0.55639512,  0.4455423 ],
            [ 0.04778727,  0.53506934,  0.79615599,  0.24200543,  0.82332594]],
           [[ 0.36535239,  0.5973006 ,  0.71075267,  0.16814739,  0.26409851],
            [ 0.85557313,  0.54190805,  0.65531428,  0.80448208,  0.54959253],
            [ 0.62112884,  0.9159606 ,  0.10186144,  0.14956198,  0.38026561],
            [ 0.70577261,  0.02682898,  0.04136858,  0.15603152,  0.47125989]],
           [[ 0.72864857,  0.09365008,  0.84137507,  0.43887926,  0.26616441],
            [ 0.31022073,  0.54251517,  0.30635049,  0.36270005,  0.85149399],
            [ 0.39371669,  0.38230285,  0.77115029,  0.22647156,  0.57128166],
            [ 0.54906932,  0.87058929,  0.72157733,  0.79480009,  0.033705  ]]])
array([ 0.04778727,  0.53506934,  0.79615599,  0.24200543,  0.82332594])
array([ 0.45117827,  0.25587538,  0.55639512,  0.24200543])
```

Why do the last two lines, `a[0][:][3]` and `a[0,:,3]`, not return the same slice of the array?  I expected them both to return what came from `a[0,:,3]`.

Comment: `a[0].T[:][3]` or easier `a[0].T[3]` this will give you the same output as `a[0,:,3]`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Each `[]` is evaluated separately by the Python interpreter, e.g.

```
In [117]: a=np.random.rand(3,4,5)
In [118]: a[0]
Out[118]: 
array([[0.98688694, 0.77224477, 0.19871568, 0.00552212, 0.81546143],
       [0.70685734, 0.72900717, 0.77127035, 0.07404465, 0.35846573],
       [0.11586906, 0.86310343, 0.62329813, 0.33089802, 0.06355835],
       [0.31098232, 0.32518332, 0.72960618, 0.63755747, 0.88721274]])
In [119]: _[:]
Out[119]: 
array([[0.98688694, 0.77224477, 0.19871568, 0.00552212, 0.81546143],
       [0.70685734, 0.72900717, 0.77127035, 0.07404465, 0.35846573],
       [0.11586906, 0.86310343, 0.62329813, 0.33089802, 0.06355835],
       [0.31098232, 0.32518332, 0.72960618, 0.63755747, 0.88721274]])
In [120]: _[3]
Out[120]: array([0.31098232, 0.32518332, 0.72960618, 0.63755747, 0.88721274])
```

Making the trailing slices explicit (for clarity to us humans):

```
In [121]: a[0,:,:][:,:][3,:]
Out[121]: array([0.31098232, 0.32518332, 0.72960618, 0.63755747, 0.88721274])
```

The middle `[:]` does not select a dimension from the original `a`.  It operates on the result of `a[0,:,:]`, and does nothing (except make a new array of the same shape and data).  The last `[3]` does not select from the third dimension of `a` - it selects from the first dimension of the array it got from the `[:]` step.  Note it returns a shape (5,) array, the size of the last dimension of `a`.  `a[0,3,:]` produces the same thing.

This on the other hand is handled entirely by the numpy indexing, and deals with all 3 dimensions at once:

```
In [122]: a[0,:,3]
Out[122]: array([0.00552212, 0.07404465, 0.33089802, 0.63755747])
```

This returns a shape (4,), the middle dimension of `a`.  `a[0,:,:][:,3]` produces the same thing.

The key point is that `numpy` operates within the Python interpreter; it does not change Python syntax.

Answer (score 2):

`a[0][:][3]` says: take 0th (sub)array, third row, and is equivalent to `a[0][3]`

`a[0,:,3]` says: take 0th (sub)array, all rows, third element (column)

Answer (score 1):

That's because `[:]` doesn't make any change to the array, so `a[0][:][3]` is same as `a[0][3]` which equals to `a[0, 3, :]`